# Roundin numbers with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, rounding

I have a pandas dataframe with a column that contains the numbers:
`[4.534000e-01, 6.580000e-01, 1.349300e+00, 2.069180e+01, 3.498000e-01,...]`

I want to round this column up to 3 decimal places, for which I use the round(col) function; however, I have noticed that panda gives me the following:
`[0.453, 0.658, 1.349, 20.692, 0.35,...]`
where the last element doesn't have three digits after the decimal.

I would like to have all the numbers rounded with the same amount of digits, for example, like: `[0.453, 0.658, 1.349, 20.692, 0.350,...]`.

How can be done this within pandas?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pandas.DataFrame.round` to specify a precision.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.round.html

```
import pandas as pd

# instantiate dataframe
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'column_to_round': [4.534000e-01, 6.580000e-01, 1.349300e+00, 2.069180e+01, 3.498000e-01,]})

# create a new column with this new precision
dataframe['set_decimal_level'] = dataframe.round({'column_to_round': 3})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame([4.534000e-01, 6.580000e-01, 1.349300e+00, 2.069180e+01, 3.498000e-01], columns=['numbers'])
df.round(3)
```

Prints:

> 0.453    0.658    1.349   20.692    0.350